# Javascript timer not displaying?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a simple timer using JS. So far, I have:

```js
var ms = 1500000;

var refresh = setInterval(function(){
    ms -= 1000;
    var minutes = Math.floor((ms / 1000 / 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((ms / 1000) % 60);
    return {
        'minutes': minutes,
        'seconds': seconds
    };
},1000);

$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#minutes').html(refresh().minutes);
      $('#seconds').html(refresh().seconds);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="minutes"></div>
<div id="seconds"></div>
```

I can't figure out why the minutes and seconds aren't showing up when I preview the html file in Chrome. I suspect I'm calling the object wrong, but I'm not sure what I should change refresh.minutes and refresh.seconds to.

Comment: `setInterval` returns a unique ID for clearing the interval later. It does not return the return value of the callback. It's not logical either since the callback is called multiple times. Definitely have a look at the [MDN `setInterval` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval).

Comment: Now here in your case what is the use of setInterval. a function can give you that.

Comment: refresh isn't even a function, so you'd be getting an error in your developer tools console, would you not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`setInterval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) does not return the result of the function you pass to it. It returns an ID of the timer that can be used to stop it. You can

1. set HTML within the function you pass to `setInterval` (and start timer when document ready) or
2. store minutes and seconds in global variables

as examples how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const start = Date.now();
const target = Date.now() + 1*3600*1e3; 

const timeLeft = () => {
  const left = target - Date.now();
  if (left < 0) return false;
  return {
    min: Math.floor(left/60e3),
    sec: Math.floor((left/1e3)%60)
  };
};
let i; // for setInterval handler
const update = () => {
  let data = timeLeft();
  if (!data) {
    // stop the timer
    clearInterval(i);
    return;
  }
  $('#minutes').text(data.min);
  $('#seconds').text(data.sec);
};

// save setInterval result for ability to stop the timer
i = setInterval(update, 1000);
update();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="minutes">0</span>:<span id="seconds">0</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

`setInterval` Always returns an id. It is not a regular function which can return a value of user's choice.

The best way to achieve what you need is to directly update your html from inside your interval function.

```
var ms = 1500000;

$(document).ready(function() {
   setInterval(function(){
      ms -= 1000;
      var minutes = Math.floor((ms / 1000 / 60));
      var seconds = Math.floor((ms / 1000) % 60);
      $('#minutes').html(minutes);
      $('#seconds').html(seconds);

   },1000);
});
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation of the error they made and the changes you made so that others can learn. This will make your answer much more useful. "Try this code" is a useless statement.

Comment: @Jai I would rather not debate on grammar or the choice of words here

Comment: @RohitAgre technical terms dear! not to debate.

Comment: @jai I would love it if you would correct me rather than just point out the defect. it would be helpful so that i don't do the same mistake again :)